# Control run of depends target ant?

Tags: ant

Based on whether a certain property is set I want to decide whether I want to run a target **and its dependencies**

Now I know that the "if" attribute can only control the run of the target in which it is specified and not the dependencies.

Is there any variant of "if" or any other alternative which would ensure that I control the run of a target and its dependencies too.

One alternative which comes to my mind it to have "if" attribute in all the dependent targets. But that seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been asked before in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376366/is-there-is-a-way-to-check-ant-target-condition-before-target-dependencies-get-e). The answer there applies very well. However, depending on how frequently the target is going to be invoked, another solution (more readable than the mentioned answer) is to use the [`if`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) task from [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/):

```
<if>
   <equals arg1="condition_prop" arg2="some_value" />
   <then>
      <antcall target="target_with_dependencies" />
   </then>
</if>
```